# difference between mvn clean install -U and eclipse project => Maven => Update Project

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

Are both the things are doing the something different or not?

As the second one, when you right click on any maven project on eclipse go to Maven and then Update project.

First is pretty much clear that it clean and artifacts from target and generate the artifacts into target and local repository.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you start Maven to build a jar/war/ear and install it in your local repository. It is Maven mechanism. It also updates your dependencies through the `-U` flag.

In the second case, you start a procedure of the m2eclipse plugin that updates you dependencies. It will not write any artifacts to your local repository. It also does not run a full build.

Comment: so when I do mvn package it also get update/download the dependency from online maven repository right so how does it is different in case of m2eclipse plugin?

Comment: `mvn package` runs a maven build while m2eclipse mimicks some parts of the build.